# Weird primary prompt string

Tags: gnome-terminal, mint, terminator

I'm using Linux Mint 18 (I know it's not Ubuntu but this is the closest place I could get). In my terminals `gnome-termnal` and `terminator`, the primary prompt string is displayed with some additional white spaces before the `$` sign:

```
  username@computer /etc $
```

Instead of

```
  username@computer:/etc/$
```

It doesn't seem to be terminal specific since different terminals show the same thing. Is there a setting for this somewhere?

Comment: What you are referring to as a "terminal file path" is known as the *primary prompt string* aka `PS1` - there's usually a setting for it in your shell's configuration file e.g. `~/.bashrc`. See for example [Bash prompt basics](https://linuxconfig.org/bash-prompt-basics)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, they aren't weird. This is the standard Linux MINT displaying. To change it temporarily, you can change the PS1 variable in the format you want. What you want is most likely:

```
export PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w/\$'
```

Explanation:
`export PS1=` changes the PS1 variable
`\u@\h:` stands for the display `username@hostname:`
`\w/\$` is for `/Current/Path/$`

---

To change it permanently you have to change the .bashrc file, therefore type the following(I chose nano as text editor)

```
nano ~/.bashrc
```

Once done, search for a section with something like this:

```
if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
if [[ ${EUID} == 0 ]] ; then
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\/[\033[00m\]\$ '
else
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w/\[\033[00m\]\$ '
fi
else
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w/\$ '
fi
```

Here you have to do the same as before, only that this time you have to change it three times. The first two include color codes, as they are for the normal terminal(the [...] are color codes). The third is the one used in tty1 or tty2... and here you can just paste the one from the temporarily version. After editing your file save the changes and type

```
. ~/.bashrc
```

for the changes to take effect.

Here is the section with the formatting you want for Linux MINT 18.1 "Serena":

```
if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
    if [[ ${EUID} == 0 ]] ; then
        PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\/[\033[00m\]\$ '
    else
        PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w/\[\033[00m\]\$ '
    fi
else
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w/\$ '
fi
```

If you don't want the full path but only the current directory, change the \w to a \W.